# string index out of bounds from Jsoup response

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup, stringindexoutofbounds

My android app gets StringIndexOutOfBound exceptions in some devices and also works perfectly otherwise in some devices

here is my code

```
try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(PostLink).header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0").get();
            String FullPage = document.toString();
            int startIndex = FullPage.indexOf("//");
            int endIndex = FullPage.indexOf("?", startIndex);
            String DownloadableLink = FullPage.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            Log.i("URLFETCH", DownloadableLink);
            if (DownloadableLink.length() > 0 && DownloadableLink.startsWith("//m") && DownloadableLink.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                return new basic(Name, PostLink, document.title(), "https:" + DownloadableLink);
            } else {
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                reference.child("Errored").push().setValue(new basic(Name, PostLink, document.title(), "https:" + DownloadableLink));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this is what i am doing in my 'AsyncTask' in 'doinbackground' method, so i also make DB ref to get information to know about why its causing or on which type of URL being causes my app to crash.

Comment: Well I would guess the exception occurs when `FullPage.indexOf("//")` or `FullPage.indexOf("?", startIndex);` return `-1`. Hard to tell if you can't reproduce this. At least, add the stacktrace in your question using the [edit]. This won't be a [mcve] but it will be a start.

Comment: i have my app published on Play , so i can say that 100 out of 20 devices causing errors and 80 are 1000% working perfectly so i dont think this indexes causing error or if than why ? :( :(

Comment: Maybe the website returns an empty or not complete response to certain devices.

Comment: If you don't provide the stacktrace, all I can do is suggestion. `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` can occurs from most of `String` method using `index` like `substring`. Both values came from the two line I have suggested... so one of those index are probably wrong.

Comment: i also tried if there error in catch block , so make a entry into Firebase DB but noting found any in DB , any way to track why this causing :( :( please guide

Comment: Where is `PostLink` defined, is it dynamic ? PS: you have a "POST link" but uses `get` ?

Comment: You track this down by logging the content of the page along with the index values you're trying to get

Comment: yes it is dynamic , it is called when user copied a URL , than the copied url is than arrives there PostLink

Comment: I would guess the response from that copied URL doesn't return a response that is correct for your method. If you can get one of the URL that fail, you will be able to reproduce this

Comment: ok thanks , i'll now try to check wether response from site isn't null than perform further